# Android: possible update replaced fragment?

Tags: android, performance

Is it possible to update the replaced fragment? For example, FragmentA got a variable stored value 5 and display on the screen, after replaced by FragmentB by using (FragmentTransaction().replace()). And user will do something on FragmentB, once user pressed backbutton, FragmentA will call from backstack, and value will be updated accordingly user did on fragment B.

I known once user press backbutton, the FragmentA will refresh/reload. But I do use a variable to control or restrict FragmentA refresh the whole fragment. I just wish to update the only view. If got example will be better.

Comment: Post some code which you want to update or refresh the view.

Comment: currently i am thinking how to make it possible.. so my code is not form yet. because i am new to android, and finding the better approach to stop the previous fragment refresh or reload. because i did implement pull-to-refresh-list-view in the fragment.. if i refresh the whole fragment will affect the data that get from pull-to-refresh and user not be able back to the clicked view. unless user pull again and scroll back to the view.  but this seem not efficiency. so i have to stop the fragment refresh.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you right, there are different approaches to read variable from FragmentB in the FragmentA

1. Use activity variable (Fragments are loaded within the same activity, right?)
2. Use shared preferences
3. Use some static variable
4. Use fragment communication approach http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html